# Why does progress { border: 0 } remove the default appearance of <progress>?

Tags: html, css

**Tested in:** Chrome 23, Firefox 15, Opera 11 (don't have IE10 or Safari 6)

With this HTML:

```
<progress value=3 min=1 max=10></progress>
```

and this CSS:

```
progress { border: 0 }
```

...the default browser rendering of the element disappears. Instead, it's replaced by a basic bar. Firebug and Chrome's web inspector indicate that the element did not initially have border-width.

Oddly, if `0` is replaced with `none`:

```
progress { border: none }
```

...Chrome is unaffected, but FF and Opera are the same.

Incidentally, how then can this basic bar be styled? Where does documentation for this sort of thing (and others, such as styling `input[type=file]`) exist?

---

**Screenshots:**

The first progress bar is always the native, unstyles variant.


Chrome 23, Windows 8:

[image: Chrome 23, Windows 8]

IE 10, Windows 8:

[image: IE 10, Windows 8]

Chrome 23, Mac OS X 10.6.8:

[image: Chrome 23, OS X 10.6.8]

Firefox 15, Mac OS X 10.6.8:

[image: Firefox 15, OS X 10.6.8]

Opera 12, Mac OS X 10.6.8:

[image: Opera 12, OS X 10.6.8]

Comment: `border:` is the shorthand.  Does `border-width: 0;` give you more consistent results?

Comment: PS: You just said that you don't have IE 10. ;)

Comment: You may be thinking "but no browsers have a border around the body element by default". This is not strictly true. Internet Explorer has a transparent or invisible border around elements

Comment: @Sparky `border-width: 0` gives the same results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the exact same reason that applying that style to a `<button>` makes it not look like a native button anymore.

Many UI components such as `<input>`, `<button>`, `<select>`, `<progress>` and so on are rendered as native controls. However, is any presentation styles are applied to them, such as `background-color`, `border`... then they can't be rendered natively and are therefore done manually by the browser using the given styles. As such, they may appear very different to how they would normally be.

Comment: I believe the correct term for components like `input type="file"` and the newer HTML5 elements (date, color, etc) is *Shadow DOM*.  They're basically a black box containing elements that we can't touch.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Now where could I find any documentation about styling these components? I'm sure it requires the use of a lot of pseudo-elements.

Comment: @charles Well, I've been making progress bars without the `<progress>` tag for a while. Just a couple of `<div>` tags work nicely. This means I can style it as much as I like.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same reason as how it kills input button/submit styles as well. They're rendered in a special way(that's not the correct word, I know), so they're broken once you change their default style.

I would suggest you sticking to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), only downside to this would be the extra kilobytes. And you can serve a wider area of users with keeping same functionality & appearance.

Refer to the section, [jQuery UI Progressbar Examples](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)